# How to send a bitmap data to the main thread from a background thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, handler

I'm creating a face detection app and to decrease the workload on the main thread I'm using a background thread. The code is given below.

```
Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

    Log.d ("Thread", "Thread has started");

    for (Feature feat : mClassifierFiles.keySet()) {
        mFaces.put(feat, cvHaarDetectObjects(grayImage,  mClassifiers.get(feat), mStorages.get(feat), 1.1, 3,
                        CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING));

        if (mFaces.get(feat).total() > 0) {

            Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize(); 
            YuvImage yuvimage=new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, previewSize.width, previewSize.height, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, previewSize.width, previewSize.height), 100, baos);
                byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);
            saveImg(bmp);

            }

    postInvalidate();
    opencv_core.cvClearMemStorage(mStorages.get(feat));

    }
     }
 });

 background.start ();
```

Now, I understand that the saving image part should be done in the main thread. Now what I don't get is, how to send the 'bitmap bmp' to the main thread?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is to use an AsyncTask. It allows you to do some work in a background thread and then get the result on the main thread. Look it up and it will be obvious how to use it.

By the way, I don't see why you should do the saving of the bitmap on the main thread. That's a slow operation and should also be done in the background thread. Only displaying the image (or other UI interactions) should be done the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Either define a `BroadcastReceiver` and send an `Intent` from your worker thread, since `Bitmap` is `Parcelable`. You can also use startIntent if you want to launch a new activity to handle the bitmap, thus you won't need to define a BroadcastReceiver. Or define an `Handler` in your main thread, pass it to your worker thread and then post a `Runnable` to be executed on the main thread. You can also use `runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: In case of handlers, can I just use 'handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(bmp))'?

Comment: Yeah sure you can, sorry forgot to mention that! AsyncTask as suggester in the other post is also a very good solution.

Comment: But apparently, AsyncTask should be used only if the code inside the thread takes a few seconds to run, which is not the case in my code.

Comment: It is the suggested way to use it. It is due to the fact that different AsyncTasks may run sequentially (unless you use executeOnExecutor) and thus one long running AsyncTask may block all the others. Moreover if you have a reference to an Activity or UI Component, it may be not visible anymore once the AsyncTask has ended. By the way, if you have to save the bitmap to a file, do everything in a worker thread. Use the main thread only if the bitmap needs to interact (e.g. be shown) with the UI.